# Web Scraping with Puppeteer. If can't get a selector multiple times go to another element

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm saving URLs from a playlist of a video player.

The sequence of actions:

1. Click on a video
2. Find video element and get it's `src`
3. Add `src` to an array

Everything is going just fine, but sometimes there is an element I can't get it `src` from. So what I want to do is to try to get element's `src` for 5 times and if it fails on the 5th time, then I should push the counter's (`i`) value in the array instead of the URL and click on the next video and get `src` of the next element. Please let me know how I can do it.

Here is my current code which clicks one by one and gets element's `src` and just freezes if it can't get element's `src`:

```
const links = await page.evaluate((SELECTORS) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const items = document.querySelector(SELECTORS.list).childNodes;
        let i = 0;
        const urls = [];
        const video = document.querySelector(SELECTORS.video);

        let counter = 0;
        const limit = 10;
        var timer = setInterval(() => {
            const url = video.getAttribute('src');
            if (!urls.includes(url)) {
                urls.push(url);
                i++;
                if (items[i]) {
                    setTimeout(items[i].click(), 2000);
                } else {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve(urls);
                }
            }
        }, 10);
        items[0].click();
    });
}, SELECTORS);
```